# Rescue an unrecognized OS with Fedora 14

Tags: fedora-14, rescue

I freshly installed Fedora 14 and working fine till my 1 TB hard disk suddenly showed "SMART TRIPPED". I brought another 1 TB hard disk and thought about installing Windows XP on it and then copy data from Fedora.

So I put XP bootable into the DVD drive and on partition look-up, I selected the by best selection the biggest non partitioned drive 1TB (the Fedora drive contained two partitions of 500 MB and 950 GB) but I found XP is reporting some unknown OS may be there, so I skipped by pressing F3 to quit.

I found out that some 8 MB is already allocated from that non partitioned drive. (I do this as Fedora 14 disk utility though recognize the disk failed to do the formatting of this drive).

Now Fedora 14 failed to boot with "unrecognized"

I assume my boot record/MBR is corrupted. Trying to recover using the Fedora 14 installation cd, but strange enough, as I read in a forum, there is no rescue mode in the boot menu. I have these five options listed.

1. Boot
2. Boot (Basic Video)
3. Verify and Boot
4. Memory Test
5. Boot from local drive.

I tried 1,3 and 5 and 1/3 boot from DVD as live user. While 5 is similar to that I get "unrecognized" without DVD

How can I rescue the system?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like XP overwrote the MBR, thus rendering you unable to boot into Fedora. You probably need to reinstall Grub.

Sadly, the Live CD has no rescue mode, but you can [download](http://chi-10g-1-mirror.fastsoft.net/pub/linux/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/x86_64/iso/Fedora-14-x86_64-disc1.iso), burn, and boot from CD1 of the [Fedora Install media](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-all) to get into rescue mode.

Once you boot from CD1, type **linux rescue** at the prompt. Answer the dialogs and once you get to the prompt, enter the command:

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
```

Then, do to fix the bootloader type

```
/sbin/grub-install /dev/hda
```

Note that the above command assumes that **/dev/hda** is your Fedora partition (which is usually the case). You may need to change **/dev/hda** to the correct partition for your Fedora installation.

After you fix the bootloader, reboot the system and, hopefully, you can now boot Fedora.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped..Just like to know after recovering how can i transfer the whole image to other hard disk of similar capacity. both are 1TB capacity. the original one is failing so instead of fresh install, update and lot more and then finally copy data...somehow want to image the first hard disk completly. this way i can wipe out defetive hard drive and let it sent for replacement.

Comment: @cd10anil You might want to open another question about how to copy a disk image, since that is a little different from your original problem.